# How to avoid page refresh from f5 key when captcha come in Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my application a `Captcha` is coming at after every 12 minutes. In this there is no such validation applied to avoid `page refresh`, so because of this when `Captcha` come on the screen and user press the `F5 key` the page refresh and `captcha disappear` from the screen without filling the `Captcha` details into the textbox. Now i want when the captcha come on the screen, User `can not do refresh` on the page until he `submitted the captcha`.

Here is the ASPX code for captcha and javascript which is calling Captcha after 12 minutes

```
function ShowNewPage() {
    var callbackFunctionArray = new Array(CloseCaptchaPopUp);
    modalWin.ShowURL('Captcha.aspx', 225, 290, 'Please enter characters dislayed in image to proceed', null, callbackFunctionArray);
}
```

Aspx Page

```
<div id="Popup_content">
        <div class="box1">
            <div class="popupheadrow">
                <p class="title">
                    Please enter text below:
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyrow" align="center">
                <div class="row" style="min-height: 18px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  style="color:Green; font-size: 0.8em;" Text=" "></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="CaptchaImage.aspx" Style="width: 255px" />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtimgcode" runat="server" CssClass="fields" TabIndex="1" MaxLength="10"
                        AutoComplete="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:Button ID="CaptchaSubmit" CssClass="submit" runat="server" OnClick="CaptchaSubmit_Click"
                        Text="Submit" Height="26px" />
                         <asp:Button style="display:none" id="btnHidden" runat="server" OnClick="btnHidden_Onclick" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function () { btnHidden.click(); }, 60000);
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function CloseCaptchaModalPopup() {
                window.parent.modalWin.CallCallingWindowFunction(0, 'Information Saved Scucessfully');
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could modify your solution and instead of showing the captcha every 12 minutes, check 12 minutes since latest time the user filled in a captcha (stored in a cookie, session or whatever you prefere...). then the captcha would show even after a page refresh.

Comment: Actually what i want is when Captcha come on screen user can not refresh the page @Daniel Stackenland

Comment: The purpose of a captcha is to stop non-humans to use the webform, if you just stop the keybord input of "F5" you probably will not stop any bot from avoiding the captcha.